# Swift Notification Not Firing

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am having a little bit of trouble. I am trying to use the notification center to alert the app that some content is done loading. After the user signs up or logs in successfully I create the view controller and then and then make it the root view controller using the blow

```
  func finishLoggingIn() {
       // print("Finish logging in from LoginController")
        let homeController = HomeViewController()
        self.loginButton.stopAnimation(animationStyle: .expand, completion: {
            self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeController
            self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        })
    }
```

The login button just creates a loading animation on the button for UI purposes.

When I first enter the controller I add the observer for the notification.

```
let MainVCSetup = Notification.Name("mainVCComplete")



NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleRootViewSwitch), name: MainVCSetup, object: nil)
```

When the content in my mainVC is done loading I post this same notification to the Notification Center like so

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MainVCSetup, object: nil)
```

However this function never fires off no matter what I do

```
@objc func handleRootViewSwitch(){
    print("Trying to handle root view switch attack")
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: MainVCSetup, object: nil)
}
```

If anyone notices where I went wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Not seeing anything obvious. Have you verified, through break point and/or print statements, that both the addObserver and post are running?

Comment: @GntlmnBndt yeah I have

Comment: Could the post be happening before the addObserver?

Comment: @GntlmnBndt no I believe it has to do with timing I did a little debugging and I found. out that the view disappears before the notification even gets a chance to post